# Ruby FTP 504 Error

Tags: ruby, ftp

when i try to put file onto server i get this error "504 Command not implemented for that parameter".

I'm logged in, can change directory, get current directory, but when i use put() or list() i get error.

Anybody know what's the problem :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem lies with the FTP server that doesn't allow to use Active Mode.
Need to use Passive Mode.